# Best way to upload document to a cross domain

Tags: 2007, development, web-services

what will best way for me to upload a document to a different site collection in a different domain (also a different farm) using some credentails.

Should i use List.asmx web services

or

Should i use HTTP Web request instead ?

i am using 2007 and site collection i need to upload document is HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement you could use the Web Services or the BCS